# How to remove lines with repeated value from a text file

Tags: python, bash, shell

i have a text file with various codes (one code per line) in a column and some of them appear more than once (always in order). I would like to know how can i remove those lines with repeated values.

Example: File1.dat

```
84578    
84581    
84627    
84761    
84761    
84792    
84792   
84792    
84886    
84886    
84905    
84905    
84905
```

I would like the output to be:

```
84578    
84581    
84627    
84761    
84792    
84886    
84905
```

Note: In my file there are no empty spaces between lines.
Any solution would do, scripts, terminal commands, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `uniq` as below, or `sort -u -o file file` will also work AND allow for case where data is not perfectly sorted. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the duplicate lines are consecutive, With Linux/MSYS you can simply use `uniq`

Output with your data:

```
$ uniq lines.txt
84578
84581
84627
84761
84792
84886
84905
```

Python solution using generator comprehension to check if first line or line different from previous to issue the line in the output file:

```
with open("lines.txt") as fr,open("uniq.txt","w") as fw:
    for line in (x for i,x in enumerate(fr) if i==0 or lines[i-1]!=x):
        fw.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open("FileWithDublicates.txt","r");
lines = file.readlines()
lines = set(lines)
file.close
file = open("FileWithDublicates.txt","w");
for line in lines:
    file.write(line)
```

This should do the trick. 
But also the line break will only exist once